# Inserting small arrows (triangles) in bottom axis pointing up with R

Tags: r, data-visualization

I'm using the following code to insert vertical lines in a timeseries plot:

```
abline(v=as.Date("2007-09-19"),col="red",lty=2)
abline(v=as.Date("2008-03-10"),col="red",lty=2)
abline(v=as.Date("2008-04-28"),col="red",lty=2)
abline(v=as.Date("2009-08-07"),col="red",lty=2)
```

But I would rather prefer a small triangle pointing up in the bottom axis, along with a label. Hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a variety of ways.  You could use a pch = '^' and put that near the bottom or look up an arrow symbol character.  Also you could just do what you're doing with the arrows() command and draw short arrows instead of abline().  With arrows you would need to specify both ends instead of just the horizontal position.. e.g.

```
arrows(as.Date("2009-08-07"),0, as.Date("2009-08-07"), 0.5, col="red",lty=2)
```

Comment: Thnks! Any way to add a small, filled triangle?

Comment: @Hugo See my response with `pch`.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer to use dedicated symbol for that purpose. For example, use `points()` with `pch=17` (filled triangle) like in the example below:

```
dd <- dotplot(m~i|p,data=res.EQ.long,subset=i %in% eq5d.items.names[1:5],
              ylab="Score",ylim=c(0.5,3.5),  
              scales=list(x=list(rot=45,at=1:5,
                          labels=eq5d.items.names[1:5],cex=c(.8,.8))),
              main="EQ-5D",
              panel=function(x,y,subscripts,...){
              panel.dotplot(x,y,...)
              panel.lines(x=c(1,5),y=3,lwd=1.5, col="gray50")
              panel.segments(x0=c(1,3,5),y0=rep(2.95,3),
                             x1=c(1,3,5),y1=rep(3.05,5),
                             lwd=1.5, col="gray50")
              panel.text(x=c(1,3,5),y=3,c(0,50,100),cex=.6,pos=3)
              panel.text(x=3,y=3.2,"Health State",cex=.6,pos=3)
              panel.points(x=(4*ref[packet.number()])/100+1,y=2.9,
                           pch=17)
              panel.points(x=1:5,y=res.EQ2[1:5,packet.number()],
                           col="red",pch=19,cex=.6)
              },
              key=list(text=list(c("Mean","Median")),x=0.7,y=0.9,
                       lines=list(col=c("blue","red"),type="p",
                       pch=19,cex=.8)))
print(dd)
```

[image]

The complete list of symbols can be obtained with `show.pch()` from the [Hmisc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Hmisc/index.html) package.

Answer (score 0):

You could manually construct the triangles using the 'polygon' command.  There might be a nice way to automate the construction of these but depending on how many you want to make it probably wouldn't be too bad to figure out the coordinates by hand.